# function1 not returning conn variable

Tags: python-3.x

```
def function1():
    conn = sqlite3.connect('mydb.db')
    connection = conn.cursor()

    return conn, connection

def function2(conn, connection):
    conn.execute("""
     INSERT INTO category
     (cat_name)
     VALUES (?) """, (cat,)
     )       
     conn.commit()

def main():
    connection = function1()
    categories = function2(conn, connection)
```

It fails saying:

```
categories = function2(conn, connection)
NameError: name 'conn' is not defined
```

Any idea why? Thank you

Comment: Aren't you missing `def` on `function1` and `function2`?

Comment: Yes, my copy and paste error. theyre there, updating now

Answer (score 0):

You never defined `conn` in main(). Probably you wanted to use the values of the tuple in `connection`.

E.g.

```
conn, connection = function1()
categories = function2(conn, connection)
```

Comment: Can you explain? If i change connection to conn, wont it complain about connection?

Comment: @CodeTalk I've updated with an example. (I hope this is valid Python, otherwise you will have to manually access the values by using [0] and [1].)